# Calling result_array() breaks table..?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm looking to hit the database once, and return a MySQL resource AND an array. I have the following code in my controller to do that:

```
$result = $this->data->my_method();

$data['result_resource'] = $result;
$data['result_array']    = $result->result_array();
```

In my view, I'm calling the following:

```
$this->table->generate($result_resource);
```

When the `$data['result_array']` line is commented out, the table works as expected (i.e the column headers show) but when the `$data['result_array']` line is *not* commented out, both the `result_resource` AND the `result_array` turn to arrays. What's happening here, and how I can avoid it?

The $data array is being passed to the view in typical CI fashion:

`$this->load->view('view.php', $data);`

Running the method twice does solve the problem, but I'd prefer not to do that.

Comment: It is probably because once `result_array` array is called it get's consumed. Then you need to query the database again if you can not tell that library to move again to the beginning of the result. I don't know if that is possible by the library. You should also add to your question how you assign these variables to the view (even if it sounds clear to you, just to make that part visible in your question).

Comment: Thanks, hakre, I updated with that info. I'm not sure I follow what you mean by 'consumed' and 'move to the beginning of the result'. Does only one instance of the resource exist, even though I've assigned it to two distinct variables?

Comment: With database result sets, it's like with a file: You start at line one, and when data is fetched, the cursor moves on until the last line. After that, there is nothing more to fetch. Telling the cursor to move to the first line (again) then might work. However it's not always the case with database result sets that you can change the position of the cursor. Better to understand?

Comment: It happens as pointed out. The `generate` function is creating the table from the passed result object, and so the call to `result_array` return an empty array. If you need the data in `result_array` as well as generate the table, then change view to `$this->table->generate($result_array);`.

Comment: The problem, though, is that when I generate the table with the array, the table headers don't show. If I use the object, they do show (default CI functionality) - so I'd ideally stick with that (or figure out how to dynamically determine the column names, which at this point might be easier).

Answer (score 0):

This stuff about the result_array() being "consumed" is nonsense - it is simply an object that hasn't been run at all. You can use it over and over

I put your code into a controller - including the table->generate() - and everything worked just fine for me.

$result is the base object that includes the connection resource, etc & really isn't what you want to use. It works because the table library is set up so that if you DO pass that, it will look for the result_array() for you, but it isn't really the standard way of doing this.

I think you prolly have something else in your code you've looked past that is causing the trouble. Try getting rid of the $result code, and just run:

```
$result = $this->data->my_method();
$data['result_array']    = $result->result_array();
var_dump($data['result_array']);
echo $this->table->generate($data['result_array']);
```

and check everything looks normal. I suspect you'll do a facepalm at some point :-)